# where can i download MGTwitterEngine for iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

this is the MGTwitterEngine page code ! but how can i download it ? 
and has any sample code?

http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine-1.0.8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout that code repository using [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). Just install it and write in console

```
svn co http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine-1.0.8/
```