# From where can i download MGTwitterEngine source code

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where can i download MGTwitterEngine for iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438726/where-can-i-download-mgtwitterengine-for-iphone-sdk)

I have to integrate twitter in my application. Can anybody give me link for downloading MGTwitterEngine source code. I read on net this is good source code for integration of twitter in application.

If some body has another link please provide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the result of typing mgtwitterengine into google?

Comment: This may be a duplicate question, but it looks like the answer has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's on [github](http://github.com) here https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine.